# Read mutiple values from ini file into TCombobox

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I have an ini file which contains the following:

```
[Colours]
1 = Red
2 = Blue
3 = Green
4 = Yellow
```

In my app I have a TComboBox which I would like to populate with the colours in the ini file.

Does anyone know how I'd go about this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a list of names in a section by using `TIniFile.ReadSection()` and then iterate to get the values:

```
procedure TForm1.LoadFile(const AFilename: String);
var
  I: TIniFile;
  L: TStringList;
  X: Integer;
  N: String;
  V: String;
begin
  I:= TIniFile.Create(AFilename);
  try
    L:= TStringList.Create;
    try
      ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
      I.ReadSection('Colours', L);
      for X := 0 to L.Count-1 do begin
        N:= L[X]; //The Name
        V:= I.ReadString('Colours', N, ''); //The Value
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(V);
      end;
    finally
      L.Free;
    end;
  finally
    I.Free;
  end;
end;
```

As an alternative, you could also dump the name/value pairs within the section into a single `TStringList` and read each value using the string list's built-in capabilities...

```
procedure TForm1.LoadFile(const AFilename: String);
var
  I: TIniFile;
  L: TStringList;
  X: Integer;
  N: String;
  V: String;
begin
  I:= TIniFile.Create(AFilename);
  try
    L:= TStringList.Create;
    try
      ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
      I.ReadSectionValues('Colours', L);
      for X := 0 to L.Count-1 do begin
        N:= L.Names[X]; //The Name
        V:= L.Values[N]; //The Value
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(V);
      end;
    finally
      L.Free;
    end;
  finally
    I.Free;
  end;
end;
```

On a side-note, Ini files do not have spaces on either side of the = sign, unless of course you want that space as part of the actual name or value.

Comment: `ComboBox1.Items` is a `TStrings`, but `L` is a `TStrings` too. You can probably assign `L` to `ComboBox1.Items` directly, without the loop.

Comment: @Rudy The loop isn't only to add the items, but also to extract the values. I had my answer to assign the list at first, until I realized the list actually contains the names, not the values.

Comment: @JerryDodge: `ReadSection()` extracts the names only, so you have to call `ReadString()` separately to read the values. if you use `ReadSectionValues()` instead then it returns the names and values at the same time so you don't have to call `ReadString()` at all. Then you can loop through the `TStrings` using the `TStrings.Names[]` and `TStrings.ValueFromIndex[]` properties as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Exactly, but `ReadSectionValues()` returns *both* the name and value, such as `1 = Red` instead of just `Red`. So you still need to iterate either way. My point was you can't just assign the list to the `Items` property as Rudy was suggesting.

Comment: @JerryDodge: `ReadSectionValues()` populates the `TStrings` with `name=value` strings, and the `Names[]`, `Value[]` and `ValueFromIndex[]` properties know how to split `name=value` strings.  Yes, you have to iterate so you can split the INI data and use the individual names and values as needed.  I would not populate the ComboBox from the INI directly.

Comment: @Remy Yes, that's essentially what I just said. Either way works, but my comment was in response to Rudy about directly assigning the list to the combo box without iterating.

Comment: @Jerry: I know. I had already removed my comment. I guess you saw it just before I removed it.

Comment: I guess Remy never saw my comment, so he doesn't know why you wrote that. <g>

Answer (score 1):

try this, without reading the file twice:

`uses IniFiles;`

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lIni : TIniFile;
  i: Integer;
begin
  lIni := TIniFile.Create('c:\MyFile.ini');
  try
    lIni.ReadSectionValues('Colours', ComboBox1.Items);
    for i := 0 to ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
      ComboBox1.Items[i] := ComboBox1.Items.ValueFromIndex[i];
  finally
    FreeAndNil(lIni);
  end;
end;
```